# How can I improve a biased CNN model performance ? (Keras, Tensorflow)

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

Model is producing only one output for all testing images, though the test set has all possible classes.

I've already tried using different optimizers and loss functions.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=x.shape[1:], activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=32)
```

Expected result: Predict parasitized or uninfected sample for the given image.

Actual result: Predicting always the same class. Either all images as parasitized or all images as uninfected.

Comment: you need to add more details like how many images per class, image size etc.

Comment: how are you testing the classifier? What is the training and validation accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
```

You can also do it in another way by treating like a categorical problem so your code should be like this `tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation=' softmax')`  and also loss should be categorical cross-entropy.

Problem: Your model seems to be a much simpler one which is unable to generalize the data to make a prediction, instead use a pre-trained model and use the feature extraction and finetune method if you have less data. hope this will help you good luck:

Comment: Nope. when we use sigmoid function the number neurons is 1 as it gives value between 0-1. It's mostly used for binary classification.
PS: i've tried doing that too.

Comment: i think you should use softmax as activation functions after dense layer and class number to be 2

Comment: You already said that in your answer, and it is not correct; for binary classification problems, the combination of `loss="binary_crossentropy"` and `activation='sigmoid'` is perfectly valid and the most usual choice